# Network printer (Source Technologies ST9530) prints pdf with different margin

Tags: pdf, network-printer, margins

I'm printing a pdf, sending it to a couple of printers on the network here (printer models: Source Technologies ST9530 and ST9730) and they print the document, but they both are shifting the content to the right and up, resulting in part of the right side cutting off.

I have tried setting it to 'Actual Size' before I print, but it doesn't make a difference.

However, I do get the expected result when printing to other printers in my office (dell, hp).

I have downloaded the printer driver from here: https://www.sourcetech.com/support/printer-drivers

I'm running Windows 7 but others with Windows 10 have similar results.

Does anyone know how to check/edit this printer's default margin settings?
I suspect that's what's making the pdf print incorrectly.

As far as I can tell, I don't have issues with any fonts on the document.